# Developing exploded war in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, war, gradle

I have a project with standard maven layout:

```
src/main/java
src/main/webapp
```

I want to develop this project in Eclipse in such a way, that Eclipse would compile my classes into exploded war folder, smth like this:

```
build/webapp/WEB-INF/classes
```

And I do not use maven as a build tool, I use gradle. Is it a way to configure Eclipse, that my output folder of the project is of correct structure for exploded war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this by adding the following to your build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: "eclipse"

eclipse {
  classpath {
    defaultOutputDir = file("${buildDir}/webapp/WEB-INF/classes")
  }
}
```

This sets the output dir to the correct directory. Also take a look at the [Gradle DSL reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html#org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath%3adefaultOutputDir)

Comment: Can I instruct Eclipse at the same time to copy resources from src/main/webapp to build/webapp ?

Comment: I have realised that the question does not reflect my complete problem, so I will accept your answer :) Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

```
task explodedWar(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/exploded"
    with war
}
war.dependsOn explodedWar
```

With these lines of code in your web module build.gradle you can have your generated war exploded